# Failed connection UDP Server C# . Socket exception 10060

Tags: c#, sockets, server, udpclient, socketserver

I´m trying to make a UDP server in c# ussing Microsoft Visual Studio. Few days ago, I connected properly the client and the server, and I have been able to read and process the received data. However, I modify to add a new socket couple to the UDP server. And from this moment until now never works again. Always I receive the same exception (10060).

> UDP SERVER

```
  public class Global
        {
            //////// UDP Server Slave 1
            public const int port = 5060;
            public static UdpClient serverSocket = null;
            public static IPEndPoint clientEndpoint = null;
            public static byte[] receivedData = null;
            public static bool UDPListening = false;
            public static string[] values;

            //////// UDP Server Slave 2
            public const int port2 = 5061;
            public static UdpClient serverSocket2 = null;
            public static IPEndPoint clientEndpoint2 = null;
            public static byte[] receivedData2 = null;
            public static bool UDPListening2 = false;
            public static string[] values2;

            //////// UDP Server Slave 2
            public const int port3 = 5062;
            public static UdpClient serverSocket3 = null;
            public static IPEndPoint clientEndpoint3 = null;
            public static byte[] receivedData3 = null;
            public static bool UDPListening3 = false;
            public static string[] values3;
        }

 private void HMI_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            // Function executed (timer2_Tick) every timer2.Interval (comms)
            System.Windows.Forms.Timer timer2 = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();
            timer2.Interval = 10; //ms
            timer2.Start();
            timer2.Tick += timer2_Tick;
        }

 private void timer2_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (Global.UDPListening == true)
            {
                    //Receive UDP Slave1
                    Global.serverSocket = new UdpClient(Global.port);//Initializes a new instance of the UdpClient class.
                    Global.clientEndpoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("172.20.80.35"), 5060);//Initializes a new instance of the IPEndPoint class with the specified address and port number.
                        
                try
                    {
                        Global.serverSocket.Connect(Global.clientEndpoint);//The Connect method sets a default remote host with the value specified in the endPoint parameter.
                                                                       //Once established, there is no need to specify a remote host on each call to the Send method.
                                                                       //Handle Data
                        Global.serverSocket.Client.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket, SocketOptionName.ReceiveTimeout, 1000);
                        Global.receivedData = Global.serverSocket.Receive(ref Global.clientEndpoint);//Returns a UDP datagram sent by a remote host

                        string receivedMessage = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(Global.receivedData);//We convert in one string the data of datagram
                        char delimiter = '/';//we declare the variable in which we will look to separate the data from the string
                        Global.values = receivedMessage.Split(delimiter);//with Split function we can separate the string in substrings. We save it in a string structure


                    }

                    catch (SocketException)
                    {

                    }

                //Receive UDP Slave2
                Global.serverSocket2 = new UdpClient(Global.port2);//Initializes a new instance of the UdpClient class.
                Global.clientEndpoint2 = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 5061);//Initializes a new instance of the IPEndPoint class with the specified address and port number.
                try
                {
                    Global.serverSocket2.Client.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket, SocketOptionName.ReceiveTimeout, 1000);
                    Global.receivedData2 = Global.serverSocket2.Receive(ref Global.clientEndpoint2);//Returns a UDP datagram sent by a remote host
                    Global.serverSocket2.Connect(Global.clientEndpoint2);//The Connect method sets a default remote host with the value specified in the endPoint parameter.
                                                                         //Once established, there is no need to specify a remote host on each call to the Send method.
                                                                         //Handle Data
                    string receivedMessage2 = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(Global.receivedData2);//We convert in one string the data of datagram
                    char delimiter2 = '/';//we declare the variable in which we will look to separate the data from the string
                    Global.values2 = receivedMessage2.Split(delimiter2);//with Split function we can separate the string in substrings. We save it in a string structure


                }

                catch (SocketException)
                {

                }

                //Receive UDP Slave3
                Global.serverSocket3 = new UdpClient(Global.port3);//Initializes a new instance of the UdpClient class.
                Global.clientEndpoint3 = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 5062);//Initializes a new instance of the IPEndPoint class with the specified address and port number.
                try
                {
                    Global.serverSocket2.Client.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket, SocketOptionName.ReceiveTimeout, 1000);
                    Global.receivedData3 = Global.serverSocket3.Receive(ref Global.clientEndpoint3);//Returns a UDP datagram sent by a remote host
                    Global.serverSocket3.Connect(Global.clientEndpoint3);//The Connect method sets a default remote host with the value specified in the endPoint parameter.
                                                                         //Once established, there is no need to specify a remote host on each call to the Send method.
                                                                         //Handle Data
                    string receivedMessage3 = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(Global.receivedData3);//We convert in one string the data of datagram
                    char delimiter3 = '/';//we declare the variable in which we will look to separate the data from the string
                    Global.values3 = receivedMessage3.Split(delimiter3);//with Split function we can separate the string in substrings. We save it in a string structure


                }

                catch (SocketException)
                {

                }

                if (Global.values == null)
                {
                    richTextBox1.Text += "No Client Connected\n\r";
                    //Global.UDPListening = false;
                }
```

> UDP Client

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Security.Cryptography; namespace UdpClientProgram
{
    class Program
    {
        /*
            FOR TESTING THE SERVER
        */         //public const string password = "HyPNotiC";         static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string matrizDatos = "HYP01/1.1/2.1/3.1/4.1/5.1/6.1/7.1/8.1/9.1/10.1/11.1/12.1/13.1/14.1/15.1/16.1/1/1";
            //string matrizDatos = "HYP01/1/2/3/4/5/6/7/8/9/10/11/12/13/14/15/16/1/1";
            string matrizDatos2 = "HYP02/16.1/15.1/14.1/13.1/12.1/11.1/10.1/9.1/8.1/7.1/6.1/5.1/4.1/3.1/2.1/1.1/1/1";
            string[] matriz = new string[999];             while (true)
            {                 Console.WriteLine(matrizDatos);
                byte[] packet;
                UdpClient client = new UdpClient();
                IPEndPoint ipep = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("172.20.80.34"), 5060);
                client.Connect(ipep);
                //packet = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(cadena1);
                packet = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(matrizDatos);
                client.Send(packet, packet.Length);                 Console.WriteLine(matrizDatos2);
                byte[] packet2;
                UdpClient client2 = new UdpClient();
                IPEndPoint ipep2 = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("172.20.80.34"), 5061);
                client2.Connect(ipep2);
                //packet = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(cadena1);
                packet2 = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(matrizDatos2);
                client2.Send(packet2, packet2.Length);                 Thread.Sleep(1000);
            }             
        }
    }     }
```

I know that I have some lines without use, and also I know that I´m not ussing the socket of the 3 Slave.

Always I have the same excepttion. I´m not connecting to the remote host.

With Wireshark I have checked that I´m receiving some packets with the proper message. The client is in one Pc and the server in other.

Ty in advance.

I tryed to receive mesages from a client. I have the clients in one Pc and the server in other. Always I´m receiving the same exception (10060). I can´t connect weith the clients.

Comment: _"I connected properly the client and the server"_ - that would be interesting how you did that with a _connection-less_ protocol :D But I guess that is to say messages were able to get from client to server and vice-versa, right? - Well the first thing that jumps the eye is your apparent objection to using the object oriented features of C#/.NET. Any particular reasoning to that?

Comment: Do you have some special reason to want to use UDP? If you just want to make computers talk to each other you are probably better of using a higher level protocol. RabbitMQ/REST/MQTT/gRPC etc, there are plenty to chose from, and they will most likely be easier to use and more reliable.

Comment: I´m ussing UDP because the client will be programed at one FPGA, and TCP need more space that I can have @JonasH.

Comment: @Fildor what are you sugesting to use? I have less knowledge of c# that I want, so if you have some idea about wich function can be more usefull in this way, I hear you :)

Comment: Having a "Global" class, where 3 sets of the same static variables exist are a huge code smell. Create a non-static class and have instance members for that (i.e. properties). Then create 3 instances with different values. And I guess basic things like that will be found throughout the codebase. This way of coding can (and will) lead to quirky behavior, surprises and loads of bugs.

Comment: You also shouldn't be doing (blocking) network I/O in an event handler. Your UI shouldn't be blocked by that...

Comment: ^^ Like this C&P error : `Global.serverSocket**2**.Client.... ; Global.receivedData**3** = Globa ... `

Comment: Thank you for your answerd. I tryed to change the globlal class for the UDP server but I have the same problem. I´m not sure that I have done properly the change, because I´m not a expèrt in c#. Its my first time programing something like this. Can you provide me an example in wich I can see how to manage the new class and it instances? I don´t understand also how avoid the use of "Global.serverSocket**2**.Client". If I don´t put it, I´m always waiting to start the udpserver, and the HMI will be blocked until I found some client in the other side of the socket. Ty in advance, @Fildor

Comment: I create a new "public class UDPServer" with some attributes like:
public class UDPServer {
            public const int port = 5060;
            public static UdpClient serverSocket = null;
            public static IPEndPoint clientEndpoint = null;
}

Comment: And also a method to "connect" the socket to the proper IP and port:

public static void connectUDP1()
            {
                //Receive UDP Slave1
                UDPServer.serverSocket = new UdpClient(UDPServer.port);  
                UDPServer.clientEndpoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("172.20.80.35"), 5060);
                UDPServer.serverSocket.Connect(UDPServer.clientEndpoint);
            }

the same has done with the other sokets